# could not retrieve tables in OLE DB Source Editor while creating a new SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssms, ssis-2008

In a existing SSIS project I need to create a new package with existing OLEDB connection manager, when i create a OLE DB source editor i couldn't see the list of tables in that database as shown below.[image]

things I done ;

1. checked the 'Test connection' in connection manager
2. I disabled 'Work offline' option under SSIS > Work Offline
   Still issue persist.

Please can someone shed some light on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of database? SQL Server? Have you tried logging directly into SQL Server (i.e. in SSMS) and confirming that your user account has access to the tables.

Comment: it is a SQL Server Db and yesI have access to those tables

Comment: By the look of the warnings in the bottom left of your screenshot, there is a lot more to this story than you think. You are using SQL authentication right? Have you tried going into the connection manager and setting the password? The problem is that the password has been cleared out of the package so you aren't actually logging in. The connection manager at the bottom has a little down arrow symbol on it right?

Comment: yes you correct, after I tested the connection in connection manager I can run the package. Though every time I deploy the package to SSIDB I need to do this test connection for all the connection managers, even though some of the conn. managers I am not even modified. Is there any other way i can prevent this for every deployment?

Comment: Since the dawn of SSIS, people have been getting the error "failed to decrypt protected xml node" - please google that error. The simplest answer from my perspective is to only ever use windows authentication, never use SQL authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick. I will keep that in mind

Comment: If you action it rather than keep it in mind, you might solve you problem.